# Some years on/in

Tags: meaning, word-choice

It seems both **in** and **on** could work for denoting *after several years*. However, is there any difference between them?

> Today, a further **six years on**, they have hardly changed at all.

and

> But **five years in**, they decided they needed a change.

Comment: 'On' is unmarked, merely indicating the elapsed time from some reference point, but 'in' further connotes a programme / venture ... that has been undertaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*X years on* simply means that we are talking about something that happens five year after an earlier mentioned time.

*X years in* means that we are X years *into* something that takes a certain (usually long) time to finish.

*On* is probably more commonly used, but in the case of projects, programs and other such undertakings, *in* is used:

> The game started all right, but 15 minutes in, the first penalty was given.
>   The project seemed well-planned, but three months in, the budget needed to be readjusted.